# Pressure wave in a cup of tea casued by a bubble burst

Tags: waves, acoustics

Assume there is a cup of tea with bubbles formed on its surface by the inner wall of the cup. If one of the bubbles bursts, it causes a wavefront travelling on the surface of the tea. Is this wave travelling at the speed of sound in the tea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it happens there is a [peripherally related article on the Physics arXiv Blog](https://medium.com/the-physics-arxiv-blog/the-mystery-of-the-white-mist-on-the-surface-of-black-coffee-a1a9624edfde). This is actually about the layer of steam you get at the surface of coffee, but it also discusses the interactions with waves at the surface.

Anyhow, the answer is that the wave that propagates along the surface is a [capillary wave](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Capillary_wave), and it does not travel at the speed of sound in the liquid, though it does travel faster than [gravity waves](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gravity_wave). Capillary waves are strongly influenced by surface tension, and their velocity is dependant on the surface tension.

The sound of the bubble bursting will of course propagate down into the bulk of the tea at the speed of sound.

Comment: If only it were possible to award $+1i$ for that "sound ...will propagate...at the speed of sound"  :-)